# how to count total number of divs with in a div using php

Tags: php

I want to count total number of div within a specific div. How can I do this?
For Example:

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="single_item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="single_item">Item 1</div>   
   <div class="single_itemitem">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

I want to count all the div containing class name single_item. How can I do this?

Comment: Your should use JavaScript for this job, not PHP

Comment: I need to get this done in laravel controller function. So i need this in php.

Comment: I think your approach to this maybe a little off. Maybe look at doing something more structured. Like build up an array or object that scaffolds your divs. Then you can do a count on the array to identify the number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use **javascript** and **Jquery** not **php**.

Use a script like this to do that:

```
 var count=0;
$( ".single_item" ).each(function() {

 count += 1;
 console.log(count);
 });
```

Look that jquery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function

Comment: I think you mean $( ".single_item" ).length :)

Comment: @MihaiVilcu work also with this ;) also you can use $(this) inside The function to manage The selector

Answer (score 0):

Salman,
PHP runs on your server - it does not see or know anything about what is seen in the web browser. Whatever code you run on PHP stops BEFORE it gets to the browser.

The web browser is the client.  Typically, the client will request a page from the server - the server generates the page (either static or dynamically using languages like PHP) and serve it back to the client.

When the page is received by the client, languages such as javascript will help you manipulate the data received. Languages like javascript will also allow you to manipulate the web page on the client.

I suggest you step back a bit - forget PHP for a moment - get a simple editor, even windows notepad if thats your thing, and create a simple html page.  Once you've done that, write a simple javascript that prompts you to enter your name, and then displays "Hello " and the name that was entered.

Walk don't run. The hair on your head will thank you.

Comment: I could do this  using jquery $(''.single_item").length. But  
I need to get this done in laravel controller function. So i need this in php

Comment: So... your page is in a PHP $variable then, correct?

Comment: $count=substr_count( file_get_contents($filename), "<div");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this job with php, you can utilize php's native `DOMDocument` class. Try the following code, which will demonstrate the process:

```
<?php

$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->load("html.php");
$finder = new DomXPath($dom_document);
$classname = "single_item";
$results = $finder->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

echo $results->length;
```

in the above example your `div` lives in the `html.php` file.

The html.php file looks like below:

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="single_item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="single_item">Item 1</div>   
   <div class="single_itemitem">Item 1</div>
</div>
```